# How to configure FRR OSPF so that the route is advertised by the OSPF daemon but not added in the linux routing table?

Tags: ospf, quagga

```
ip route 1.1.1.1/32 ens33
ip route 1.1.1.2/32 ens33

!
interface ens33
ip ospf 1 area 0 192.168.84.191
!
router ospf 1
ospf router-id 192.168.84.191
redistribute static metric 10000 route-map RM-ens33
!
access-list AC-ens33 seq 1 permit 1.1.1.1/32
access-list AC-ens33 seq 2 permit 1.1.1.2/32
!
route-map RM-ens33 permit 10
match ip address AC-ens33
```

This is an example configuration which we use normally to advertise the routes 1.1.1.1/32. The problem with this configuration is that it adds an entry in linux routing table where the frr/ospf daemon is running along with advertising the route to OSPF peers. We don't want frr service to add the static route to the linux routing table and just advertise it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

make the next hop in the static route null